# How to find a string in data frame which has the text with underscore in between

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

In Data frame I have values For Ex as below :

```
Rhymes(column name)
Johny johny.yes_papa eating
sugar
No papa.open_mouth_ha ha ha
```

The output should be the list of all the strings which has underscores like:

```
yes_papa,
open_mouth_ha
```

I am trying with the below code but I am only getting column names in the dataframe:

```
df[df["Rhymes"].str.contains("_&_&_",na =False)]
```

Should I be using regular expressions to get the exact match

Comment: It would be nice to have code to easily import data (e.g. output of `df.to_json()`). Also, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method [`pd.Series.str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) returns a Boolean series, it doesn't return the strings you want.

You can instead use a custom function with `str.split`, apply this to your series, drop nulls and convert back to a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Rhymes': ['Johny johny.yes_papa eating', 'sugar',
                              'No papa.open_mouth_ha ha ha']})

def get_underscores(x):
    return next((i for i in x.replace('.',' ').split() if '_' in i), None)

res = df['Rhymes'].apply(get_underscores).dropna().to_frame()

print(res)

          Rhymes
0       yes_papa
2  open_mouth_ha
```

Comment: Hi..It worked ..Thankyou..What if there is another text appended to yes_papa like johny.yes_papa and the output should still be yes_papa..Should I put split('.') in the above code

Comment: @Ramya, Not sure what you want if multiple strings are in scope for a specific row. If possible, you should note this [in your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51722546/edit).

Comment: Hi jpp..I have updated my data frame..Can you please check..I have added a  "." for the string with underscore and still the output should be only the value with underscore.For EX : Data frame is "Johny johny.yes_papa, eating" and the output should still be "yes_papa"

Answer (score 1):

For a string, it should work like this.

```
    string = "Johny johny yes_papa eating sugar No papa open_mouth_ha ha ha"
    def find_underscore(string):
        a = []
        for i in string.split():
            for j in i:
                if j == '_':
                    a.append(i)
        return a
```

for a column of data frame:

```
    new_list = []
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        print(find_underscore(row["column_name"]))
        new_list.append(find_underscore(row["column_name"]))

    df.new_column = new_list
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get rows containing an underscore:

```
df[df["Rhymes"].str.contains("_")]
```

Or this to get just values:

```
df.loc[df["Rhymes"].str.contains("_"), "Rhymes"].values
```